# importing date value YYYY-MM-DD from excel sheet to DataTable getting only last value DD

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using the code from the below link, to import data from excel to `DataTable`. Everything is working fine except
date format value of excel cell.

While importing date value from excel the last digit is only imported. eg. 2012-12-25
becomes 25 in DataTable cell. How can I get the complete date value from excel to DataTable?

https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/297/the-best-way-to-import-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-via-asp-netga

Answer (score 0):

you have to filter the excel as text.

Right click on excel column and select format cells and then select text as catergory.